# How do I ignore the first row in an Excel macro that deletes all rows based on a criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

This macro is designed to compare the data in column C and D and if C does not match D in a certain row, it deletes the entire tow. The problem is that it deletes the headers in Row 1 on the Excel sheet because they don't match. How do I run the macro for rows 2 through 9999 instead of all 9999 rows.

```
Sub deleteNonMatchingRows()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 9999 To 1 Step -1 ' it will scan 9999 rows of the sheet. This number can be increased for larger sheets
        If Range("C" & i) <> Range("D" & i) Then
            Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a descriptive variable naming, eg. rename `i` into `iRow` you will never forget that this is your row counter, that is counting from row `9999` to row `1` in `For iRow = 9999 To 1 Step -1`. So you need to change the `1` into a `2` to omit the first row.

I recommend to use a dynamic start for your loop that automatically finds the last used row. This prevents unnecessary loop steps and you don't need to increase it for larger worksheets.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteNonMatchingRows()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column C

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1 
        If Range("C" & iRow) <> Range("D" & iRow) Then
            'Range("C" & iRow).EntireRow.Delete
             Rows(iRow).Delete 'directy delete a row
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Deletion of a row is an operation that takes quite some time. Thus, it is a good idea to make all deletions at once, uniting all rows to be deleted in a specific range `wholeRange`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteNonMatchingRows()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim wholeRange  As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("C" & iRow) <> Range("D" & iRow) Then
            If wholeRange Is Nothing Then
                Set wholeRange = Rows(iRow)
            Else
                Set wholeRange = Union(wholeRange, Rows(iRow))
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    If Not wholeRange Is Nothing Then
        wholeRange.Select       'delete this row
        Stop                    'delete this row
        wholeRange.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Once you run the code, it will stop on the `Stop` line. You will be able to see the range, which is to be deleted. The range will be selected. Once you see it, it is a good idea to delete the two rows, mentioned in the comments, you are not going to need them any more.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid loops:

```
Sub deleteNonMatchingRows()
    With Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) ' reference column C cells from row 2 doen to last not empty one
        With .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count) ' reference referenced range offset by active sheet used range columnns (to be sure you'r not overwriting already filled cells)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC3<>RC4,1,"""")" ' have referenced cells show a "1" if corresponding cells in column C and D match
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Delete ' delete all rows whose referenced column formula result is a number
            .ClearContents ' clear referenced range
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bryan, any feedback?