# Excel VBA filter and delete

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I searched the forum but wasnt able to find anything that really worked. I have a simple sheet where i want to filter column AZ for anything labeled "LOW" or "TBD" and delete only those. Then remove the filter.

I was running the below code but since it deleted each one in line it would miss some as the i would just keep going.

```
For i = 2 To access.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If access.Cells(i, 11) = "LOW" Or "TBD" Then
Rows(i).delete
Exit For
End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If access.Cells(i, 11) = "LOW" Or  access.Cells(i, 11) = "TBD" Then
```

or if you want to be a bit more fancier:

```
With access.Cells(i, 11)
    If .Value2 = "LOW" Or .Value2 = "TBD" Then Rows(i).Delete
End With
```

---

Whenever you are deleting rows, this is the best practice:

```
For i = access.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 2 Step -1
```

If it is a bit slow, consider adding the rows to a range with `Union()` and deleting the whole range. The `Union()` should be the fastest solution I guess - [How do I ignore the first row in an Excel macro that deletes all rows based on a criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350053/how-do-i-ignore-the-first-row-in-an-excel-macro-that-deletes-all-rows-based-on-a/50350507#50350507)

Comment: sorry that was what i had. Just a typo when i put it in here. the issue is that there would be say 10 "LOW" in a row and it is deleting them as they go.. So it will keep skipping cells.

Im thinking a filter and delete would be better and faster

Comment: `For i =  access.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 2 Step -1`, @JoshHudson

Comment: so again, would a filter and delete not be better and faster?

Comment: @JoshHudson - depends how many are you deleting, there should be a break even point somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you are deleting records in a range in Excel and you referencing the rows using the row number you should start at the bottom and work your way to the top.  The reason is because when you're examine row 5 and you remove it, row 6 now becomes row 5 but your loop counter increments to row 7 - thus you never examine row 6.

I would suggest:

```
Dim LastRow as Long

LastRow = access.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = LastRow To 2 Step - 1
    If access.Cells(i, 11) = "LOW" Or "TBD" Then
        Rows(i).delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: wow yeah i guess that makes more sense... I used the code above but it just stays in the for loop and never touches the if code

Comment: The `For` line should be `For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1` to tell it to **decrease** the count by 1 each time

Answer (score 0):

Toy can try this way. And why you add 11 for column index. AZ is index 50

```
Sub test2()


' Active workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Long


'*******************************************
'Adapt this vars


'define your sheets
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet
Set ws_1 = wb.Sheets("Feuil1")

'definie the last Rows
Dim lastRow_ws1 As Long

lastRow_ws1 = ws_1.Range("AZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'*******************************************


For i = lastRow_ws1 To 2 Step -1

    Dim keySearch As String
    keySearch = ws_1.Cells(i, 50).Value

    If keySearch = "LOW" Or keySearch = "TBD" Then
    ws_1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This would give error `424` to about 99.9% of the users in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses `AutoFilter` instead of running through the rows 1-by-1.  As a warning, this **will** clear any filters that you have on the data.  (Unless you have macros to save/restore filters)

```
Const FilterColumn = 52 ' Column AZ

'Clear Filters
access.AutoFilterMode = False
'Filter for data
access.UsedRange.AutoFilter FilterColumn, "LOW", xlOr, "TBD"
'If Data exists
If access.Cells(access.Rows.Count, FilterColumn).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
    'Delete visible rows
    access.Range(access.Cells(2, FilterColumn), access.Cells(access.Rows.Count, FilterColumn)).EntireRow.Delete
End If
'Clear Filters
access.AutoFilterMode = False
```