# Deleting every second row in excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to write a code, that checks how much rows there are in one sheet, then deletes every second row. The procedure should be like this:

1. Get total number of rows
2. Start with the last row, delete it
3. Go up by two rows, delete it
4. After you reach row number 2, stop

Here is my code which stops working at 8th row `activeRow = activeRow - 2`.

```
Sub trendlucid()
    Dim numOfRows As Integer
    Dim activeRow As Integer
    numOfRows = Sheets(actualsheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    activeRow = numOfRows
    Do While activeRow > 1
        Rows(activeRow).EntireRow.Delete
        activeRow = activeRow - 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

I have no idea why does it stop. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting rows, loop back:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim numOfRows As Long
    Dim activeRow As Long
    numOfRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    activeRow = numOfRows

    Dim i As Long

    For i = numOfRows To 1 Step -2
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

There is a bit faster way to delete rows, if you first save them in one range and at the end you delete the range. Thus, you use the delete operation only once:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350507/5448626

Comment: Thank you, that does work but why doesnt it work with activeRow, I'm looping it by minusing 2. Thanks

Comment: @Kyrbi - because I thought that the problem is only in the loop. `actualsheet` and `Integer` are updated in the code now.

Comment: Okay, I tried your code now, but it went through without any error but there are still every second row in my excel.

Comment: @Kyrbi - try again, I have not written the correct row to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you it does work now and it's correct answer. :)

Comment: this would work only for `UsedRange` starting from row 1. Should it start from any other row it would not and you must reference `UsedRange.Rows()`. You may see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two flaws in your code

1. unsure sheet reference

   you're counting number of `UsedRange` rows of `Sheets(actualsheet)`
   while you're deleting `ActiveSheet` rows (implicitly referenced sheet in R`ows(activeRow).EntireRow.Delete`)

   so be sure to reference the same sheet (e.g.: `ActiveSheet`)
2. unsure range reference

   `UsedRange` may start form a row different than row 1, while `Rows(index)` consider a row index starting from row 1

   So reference `UsedRange` `Rows()` instead of `ActiveSheet` (implicitly assumed) `Rows()`

all this sums up to:

```
Sub trendlucid()
    Dim numOfRows As Long ' use Long instead of Integer to avoid overflow issue for more thna some 32k rows or so
    Dim activeRow As Integer
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' reference "active" sheet 'UsedRange' range
        numOfRows = .Rows.Count ' count the number of rows of referenced range
        activeRow = numOfRows
        Do While activeRow > 1
            .Rows(activeRow).EntireRow.Delete ' reference 'UsedRange' 'Rows()' instead of 'ActiveSheet' 'Rows()'
            activeRow = activeRow - 2
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try something similar...

You don't need to use `EntireRow` with `Rows`, only `Row Index` is required and the `Delete` action will be performed to whole row.

```
Sub trendlucid()
    Dim numOfRows As Long
    Dim i As Long
    numOfRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = numOfRows To 2 Step -2
        Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```